# How to configure log4j2.properties file to create logs for specific package

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

**Below is my project structure:**

src->main->java->com->dot->filter->here are many folders (ax,by,cz) which contain the classes

src->main->java->resources->log4j2.properties

**Below is my log4j2.properties file:**

```
status = error
name = PropertiesConfig
 
property.filename = C:\\logs\\debug.log
 
filters = threshold
filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = debug
 
appenders = rolling
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}
appender.rolling.filePattern = C:\\logs\\PreviousLogs\\-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 20
 
loggers = rolling
  
logger.rolling.name = com.dite.filter.ax

logger.rolling.level = debug
logger.rolling.additivity = true
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
```

for the above configuration I couldn't generate the logs

is there anything wrong in this line `logger.rolling.name = com.dite.filter.ax`?

could any one please tell me what mistake I have done in this configuration?

or

suggest me other way to generate logs for above specified package structure

Answer (score 0):

You configuration of the `com.dite.filter.ax` logger is correct, but you didn't configure the root logger.

If you want to ignore all log messages that do not come from `com.dite.filter.ax` and its descendants use:

```
rootLogger.level = OFF
```